# how to upload image to the server against different key using MultupartFile in Flutter..?

Tags: flutter, dart, multipart

suppose you have to upload image to the Server using MultipartFile for a single key like **"image"**. you can easily can do it but if you have different types of keys for file like
**"image", "logo", "banner" etc**
so how can you handle this for different types keys..

it is working for single key like "image"

```
final request = http.MultipartRequest('PUT', url,);
    request.fields.addAll(body.toMap());

    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    if (body.image.isNotEmpty) {
      final file = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', body.image);
      request.files.add(file);
    }
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501529/flutter-how-to-send-multiple-files-to-http-post

Answer (score 0):

Add additional fields if needed

```
  request.fields['field1'] = 'value1';
  request.fields['field2'] = 'value2';
```

full code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

uploadImage(File imageFile) async {
  final url = 'http://example.com/upload-image';
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));

  // Create a MultipartFile from the image file
  var image = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFile.path);

  // Attach the MultipartFile to the MultipartRequest
  request.files.add(image);

  // Add additional fields if needed
  request.fields['field1'] = 'value1';
  request.fields['field2'] = 'value2';

  // Send the MultipartRequest to the server
  var response = await request.send();

  // Check the response status code
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Image upload successful
    print('Image uploaded successfully');
  } else {
    // Image upload failed
    print('Image upload failed with status ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

I think this will help you